# Regex get string not include double quotes python

Tags: python, regex

I am working on a web scrapper and I have a js string like this.

```
Package Title: ('"id"', ':', '1', ',', '"title"', ':', '"', '11 Dofollow and 500 Words Article')
Package Title: ('"id"', ':', '2', ',', '"title"', ':', '"', 'Basic Page and Privacy Policy Page')
Package Title: ('"id"', ':', '3', ',', '"title"', ':', '"', '2x Standart Page')
```

I want to like this, how can I do this?

```
11 Dofollow and 500 Words Article
Basic Page and Privacy Policy Page
2x Standart Page
```

I tried this but not working

```
package = re.findall(r'\'^[^"](.*?)^[^"]\'',str(jsstring))
print(package)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.findall(r"'([^']*)'\)", str(package_title_match))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u25fAz/1). *Details*:

- `'` - a single quote
- `([^']*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than a single quote
- `'\)` - a `')` substring.